# What is a proper way to set up custom labels in Angular.js Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a fragment that looks something like this:

```
<div directive config='config'>
    <p> {{somemessage}}</p>
</p>
```

Now, I need that directive to have the shared scope. But I need to set this custom message, `{{somemessage}}` custom for each instance (based on the passed in config).

How can I do that? Right now I'm messing with something like this:

```
element.children()[0].innerHTML = 'My custom msg';
```

which is awfully wrong. What would be the right way for this?

Comment: When you say 'each instance', that is a indication that you want a reusable directive, and that an isolate scope might be a better fit. Could you elaborate why it needs to be shared?

Either way, you should probably use a template in the directive, where you set this message. More info would be nice to give more advice.

Comment: Yes, I mean I want to reuse this directive inside the same scope. I wanted to make it a shared scope to avoid too many watches (because I have several properties on the scope that I need to watch from each directive and react based on that directive's config attribute. Wrong approach?

Comment: Anyway, the question is that I need to set that message to a different string in each of the directive. What is a good way to do that?